# How can I truncate text in a paragraph element based on height?

Tags: html, css

So i have a page in which there is a box, in that box it has a title and a description and after that I have a button named "Open". The problem is that sometimes the description is too big and it ruins the position of the button and everything.

So lets assume that this is my long description:

```
an instance (such as a problem to be solved) serving to illustrate a rule or precept or to act as an exercise in the application of a rule
 a parallel or closely similar case especially when serving as a precedent or model
```

And I want it to look like this after it exceeds its limited characters:

```
an instance (such as a problem to be solved) serving to illustrate a rule or precept....
```

Any idea how can I achieve this without ruining other elements?

Comment: sounds to me for a job with `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis` to truncate a text with dots. To cut it after a specific ammoutn of characters you need a `monospace font` to define the width in `em`.

```css
p {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 20em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>an instance (such as a problem to be solved) serving to illustrate a rule or precept or to act as an exercise in the application of a rule
 a parallel or closely similar case especially when serving as a precedent or model</p>
```